# Getting NULLs on dividing 1 column by another column

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am retrieving some counts like 'New Products' and 'Number of sales' grouped by quarters. I need to calculate ratios of these counts.So, my query is like this:

```
select YR, 
       QTR, 
       MAX(#ofsales) AS '# of Sales', 
       MAX(#Totalproducts) AS '# of Total Products',
       MAX(#ofsales*100/#Totalproducts) AS '% of Products Sold',
       MAX(#Totalproducts/#ofsales) AS 'Inventory'
from (union of few tables)
order by YR, QTR
group by YR, QTR;
```

The results is:

```
Yr   | Qtr   |# of Sales|# of Total products|% of Products Sold|Inventory
2016 |  1    |   5231   |       7239        |      NULL        |  NULL
2016 |  2    |   3678   |       4752        |      NULL        |  NULL
```

I am using MAX() operator because otherwise, I get errors like:

```
Column '#ofsales' is invalid in the select list because it is not 
contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause
```

In response to @mypetlion's question, here is my query without MAX() function.

```
select YR, 
       QTR, 
       #ofsales AS '# of Sales', 
       #Totalproducts AS '# of Total Products',
       #ofsales*100/#Totalproducts AS '% of Products Sold',
       MAX(#Totalproducts/#ofsales) AS 'Inventory'
from (union of few tables)
order by YR, QTR
group by YR, QTR;
```

Comment: Are any of your variables `NULL`? And just to understand, you're using the `MAX()` function, not because you want the maximum of something, but because you get an error without it? What does your query look like without the `MAX()` functions? And what are the datatypes of each of your variables?

Comment: @mypetlion, Only a couple of rows have NULL values for '# of Sales'. All other rows have proper integer values. Yes, I am using MAX() function only to avoid AGGREGATE or GROUP BY errors. I have updated my question to show query without MAX() function but it doesn't work because of aforementioned "AGGREGATE or GROUP BY errors". The variables '#ofsales' and '#Totalproducts' are SUM products so, I am sure they are of integer datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to make the division work in the original Query because of the MAX() function. Hence, as a workaround, I imported all the results into a new table and then applied division and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the denominator with the COALESCE function.  It will check if the value is NULL and return a value you give it.  Since you are trying to avoid a divide by zero error you can have it return 1.

```
select YR, 
       QTR, 
       #ofsales AS '# of Sales', 
       #Totalproducts AS '# of Total Products',
       #ofsales*100/#Totalproducts AS '% of Products Sold',
       MAX(#Totalproducts/COALESCE(#ofsales, 1)) AS 'Inventory'
from (union of few tables)
order by YR, QTR
group by YR, QTR;
```

Comment: Just tried that and now in 'Inventory' column, I am getting same values as '#ofsales' column values. Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: Anything divided by 1 will equal itself.  if you don't want to get the #Totalproducts when #ofsales is NULL then you will need to write the SQL differently.

the line: `MAX(#Totalproducts/COALESCE(#ofsales, 1)) AS 'Inventory'`
should be changed to something like:
`CASE WHEN COALESCE(#ofsales, 'N/A') == 'N/A' THEN _'Return whatever you want returned if #ofsales is NULL'_ ELSE MAX(#Totalproducts/#ofsales) END AS 'Inventory'`

Comment: Thanks, @hajile78. I get what COALESCE is doing here. But, it is returning #Totalproducts even when both #Totalproducts and #ofsales are NON-NULL. The division is not happening in any case.

Comment: It might me that you are trying to run the MAX Aggregate function on a calculated value.

Comment: yes it is because of the MAX() function. I just imported all the results into a new table and then applied division and it worked fine. But, is there a way to make it work in the original query itself (without requiring to import it into a new table)?

Comment: I don't think it can be done in the original Select statement. Your solution seems to be a good solution.